# How to select more checkboxes values for filter result?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, angular-material, observable

I have some checkboxes for filtering. And I can select one or more checkboxes. But for example you will select two checkboxes then only the last selected checkbox will show the value from the backend.

So I have this as HTML:

```html
<div class="mat-checkbox-project-absolute">
    <div *ngIf="showProjectFilter"  class="mat-checkbox-project">
        <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of returnProjectCodes; let i = index">
            <mat-checkbox
                (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                (change)="filterProjects($event, i, item);"
                [checked]="selected === i">
                    {{ item.name }}
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the method:

```
returnProjectCodes: ProjectApi[] = [];

filterProjects(event, index, item) {
    if (event.checked === true) {
        const hallo =  this.returnProjectCodes.push(item);
        console.log(hallo);
        this.extendedSearchFilterService.filterByProject(item.projectId).subscribe(pipe());
        this.datasource.filter = item.name;
    } else {
        this.datasource.filter = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: by checking length of the checked values you can able to achieve that

Comment: thank you.can you give example

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz with your code? so that we can update the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component:

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  list: any[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.list = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Администратор',
        checked: true,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Пользователь',
        checked: false,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Директор',
        checked: false,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Начальник',
        checked: false,
      },
    ]
  }

  get result() {
    return this.list.filter(item => item.checked);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list| slice:0:this.result.length+1; let ind=index;">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.checked">{{item.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this example will you a glimpse how to achieve that. This is not a great way to achieve but you can work around

Comment: Thank you. I will look at it.

Comment: give a vote up and accept my solution if it works for you @niceCoderToTheBest